# Embedded system with OpenGL, do I need loadable module support and shared lib support?

Tags: c, linux, opengl, embedded, hardware

I have an extremely bare-bones Linux system that consists of basically nothing more than a kernel and a few statically-linked binaries. I have replaced init with my own program. All drivers are compiled into the kernel. It works fine, but now I want OpenGL support. I can compile DRM support into the kernel and install Mesa 3D library which should work with the open source ATI Radeon driver, but is that enough? Do I still need to load modules into the kernel? And how are shared libraries linked at runtime? Does gcc include code in the binaries that searches for shared libraries?

Comment: Dynamic linking of shared objects that are "hard linked" into the binary is a collaborative effort of the kernel and the system C runtime library (libc). The kernel maps the shared object files into the process address space, but symbol relocation is delegated to userspace.

Comment: I don't have libc on the system or any other shared libraries. I suspect libGL itself will have dependencies, which would then require installing all the libraries it needs as well. Since Mesa is open source, shouldn't it be possible to compile a static OpenGL library (libGL.a)? I only need to run one binary on the system, and OpenGL could be statically linked into to this binary (if this is even possible).

Comment: You seem to have the misconception that OpenGL is "just" some library. In fact OpenGL is a API specification and Mesa is a implementation of that API specification. Mesa itself, i.e. that part that makes the `libGL.so` is just the OpenGL state tracker. But the real magic happens in the implementation backend, which is loaded at runtime. Regarding libc, well, sure you have one, specifically every program binary will have the functions it needs statically linked in, preferably from a small footprint libc, like dietlibc.

Comment: So in your case you'll have to build Mesa, but also its driver backends into static libraries, you'll have to configure Mesa to use a specific driver backend (the one that matches your system). And last but not least, you will need some graphics infrastructure running. OpenGL offers no functions to create a window or a framebuffer to render to. Either you use X, Wayland or talk directly to KMS/DRM (search for the `kmscube`) example program.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware OpenGL is much more than a library, but I am used to libGL being a shared library so I'm sort of in uncharted territory when it comes to statically linking the whole nine yards into my program. Ideally, I'd like to use OpenGL without X, so that gets rid of the glx/CGL functions with which I'm familiar. As you mentioned, I'd like to take directly to the DRM, since support can be compiled into the kernel. But without X, what is the replacement for the glx functions? EGL (Mesa)? Is it possible to use ONLY Mesa, e.g. Mesa(static)->DRM(kernel)->screen?

Comment: You should look at the `kmscube` example I mentioned. I'm not the original author, but I have a fork of it in my GitHub: https://github.com/datenwolf/kmscube – however it depends on a handful of shared libraries. It's certainly possible to make it fully static, but this actually means, that the graphics driver itself will end up in your program binary (the DRM part of the Linux kernel is managing GPU hardware resources, but lacks the functions to make it actually draw stuff).

Comment: Note, that I personally am a huge proponent of linking statically where it makes sense (small and essential system utilities). But when it comes to the graphics infrastructure these is one of the area where I want things to be linked dynamically, so that the drivers can be upgraded without rebuilding all the graphics programs.

Comment: I will definitely check out kmscube. One thing I am unclear on, though. You say the graphics driver will end up in the program binary. As it is now, the graphics driver is in the kernel (the boot args contain "radeonfb" as the video driver). At the moment, I think this is using the regular Linux framebuffer interface (non-DRM) but I think a DRM version of this driver exists (radeondrmfb). If the driver is in the kernel, why must it be in the binary?

Comment: No, the kernel modules are not really graphics drivers. They provide an interface to the userspace to talk to the graphics card in a direct way and enable the kernel to manage GPU memory. Also they offer KMS so that the kernel can switch the graphics mode. But other than that DRM is a rather "dumb" layer. All the interesting stuff happens in userspace in the the state tracker and DRI backends.